# Apply different transformations to different samples for parametric test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation, nonparametric

Suppose I have two samples from a population collected from different times, but their distribution looks different (e.g. sample one looks skewed right, while sample two looks bimodal). Can I apply a transformation to sample one, and a different transformation to sample two to make them both normally distributed so I can run parametric tests comparing the two samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, no sensible transformation will turn a bimodal distribution into a normally shaped one.

Second, if you apply different transformations to 2 samples and then compare them, I have no idea how you would interpret the results.

Third, if one distribution is bimodal, the mean is probably not all that meaningful.

So.... I'd recommend 1) Refining your aim and 2) Then choosing an appropriate test.

Or, in short, the answer to your direct question is "no".

Comment: Understood, thank you for your quick and clear answer!